# In C++, how does strict bottom-up analysis imply that the return type is not used in overloading resolution?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation

In Bjarne's [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=0klsAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA547&lpg=PA547&dq=bottom+up+analysis+return+type+overloading&source=bl&ots=S1lfZcFG4V&sig=PaOJU_A39WELUMgkAiL_f1AgMco&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EB3_U-rgG8TpggTA2YHQAQ&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=bottom%20up%20analysis%20return%20type%20overloading&f=false), he said,

> The insistence on strict bottom-up analysis implies that the return type is not used in overloading resolution.

It looks like that "bottom-up analysis" has sth to do with how the compiler parse the C++ codes.

What does he mean by saying this?

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Bottom-up analysis" in particular means that the type of the sub-expression has to be determined before the type of containing exression, so for example if we have an expression `g(f())` the type of `f()` has to be determined before the compiler starts the overload resolution for `g()`. This couldn't be done if we had:

```
int f();
float f();

void g(float);

// Even though g() accepts only float, bottom-up analysis implies that 
// this information is not available during resolution of f().
g(f());
```